# Flutter : Why I am getting the error message "Could not load compiled classes for build file '...\android\build.gradle' from cache"

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

I am having the following error with compiling a project I am working on. Surprising enough, I had successfully compiled it in the past, but when I came back to it weeks later, I began having the error.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred configuring project ':mercado_pago_mobile_checkout'.

> Could not load compiled classes for build file 'C:\src\flutter.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\mercado_pago_mobile_checkout-0.2.0-dev.4\android\build.gradle' from cache.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':mercado_pago_mobile_checkout' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
> Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':mercado_pago_mobile_checkout' of type org.gradle.api.Project.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning the project by running the following command in the terminal:

```
flutter clean
```

This command will remove any previously generated build files.

You should also try deleting the .gradle folder located in the root directory of your project. This folder contains cached data, and deleting it can sometimes resolve issues related to caching.

You can also try to:

- Check if the version of the Gradle plugin being used in your project
  is compatible with your current Gradle version. You can do this by
  looking at the build.gradle file of your project and comparing it to
  the Gradle plugin compatibility chart.
- Make sure that the android block in your build.gradle file is
  properly defined. It should contain all the necessary configuration
  for your Android project.

If none of the above steps work, try updating the version of the mercado_pago_mobile_checkout package to the latest version, or try downgrading it to a previous version that was known to work.